# how to change json object name (key)?

Tags: java, android

Just a quick question:

If I have a json object which contains "key/value"s like this:

```
"name":"value"
```

and I want to change the name parts to something else, what should I do? I don't want to remove and make it again.

Comment: when you say `I have a json object`, do mean you have an instance of `JSONObject`, a String representing your object, something else entirely? (in the first case, `jsonobject.put("new name", jsonobject.remove("name"));` is as straighforward as it comes).

Comment: I can't think of any argument in favor of `I don't want to remove`, since this is just manipulating simple references. JSONObject is backed by an HashMap, in which you can't change the value of the keys (for obvious hashing reason), which implies that you need to reinsert the value with the new key after having removed it.

Comment: @njzk2 I edited my question, sorry. I think the removing thing is the only one, thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Proper and compact implementation, given that `jsonObject` is the json object you are referring to and it is an instance of `JSONObject`:

```
jsonObject.put("new name", jsonObject.remove("name"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new object with the new value

```
new JSONObject(jsonobject.toString().replace("\"name\":","\"newvalue\":");)
```

Comment: which will not work if, say, the object is `{"name": "something", "other\"name":"This name has a quote in the middle"}`