# Replacing Object keyname in an Object reports "is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, json

This answer [how to change json object name (key)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26065020/how-to-change-json-object-name-key)
 provides a method of replace a name/key in a JSON object but I am running into problems getting it to work.

I am obtaining some fields from a library, such as `getColumnTitle` etc that have numbers appended that identify which column the `Title` comes from.  Because I need the values associated with a row and have a unique column grouping identifier, the appened numbers cause difficulty at the server side. hence I need to remove the numeric suffix or appended numeric value.

This is what I am trying to do with the code below, however I get a

```
TypeError: getTaskCellData.remove is not a function
```

error.

Here is the code.

```
var getColumnTitle = "hour231";
var getTaskCellData = {"hour231":23,"name":"hello world","other":"fields"}; 
var alphaTitle = getColumnTitle.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');
getTaskCellData.put(alphaTitle, getTaskCellData.remove(getColumnTitle));

 console.log(getTaskCellData)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer you linked to is for JAVA, not JavaScript... An object literal, as you have it stored in getTaskCellData, doesn't have `remove` on its prototype, so you can't use that. Personally I don't think it's worth the code to rename an object's property, simply add a new property holding the same value. If you really insist on renaming, you can do the same and additionally use `delete`.

```js
var getColumnTitle = "hour231";
var getTaskCellData = {"hour231":23,"name":"hello world","other":"fields"}; 
var alphaTitle = getColumnTitle.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');

getTaskCellData[alphaTitle] = getTaskCellData[getColumnTitle];
delete getTaskCellData[getColumnTitle];

 console.log(getTaskCellData)
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for pointing that out.  In fact in my running code I did exactly what you suggested by I just did not like the idea of pushing redundant data over ajax calls and was looking for a clean solution !   But the delete looks like it will work.   Thanks